# Is the education board eugenically selecting out unpowered humans?

Tags: novel, from-the-new-world

In the ["From the new world"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_the_New_World_(novel)) anime it seems like whenever a human child might not have powers or be underpowered then they are culled by the education board.   I've [heard it said in another answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4130/4837) by someone that read the manga, that in the manga the education board is afraid that people might become Karmic demons or harm people accidentally through clumsy power control.  However, it seems more likely that the education board doesn't want to create an unpowered under class of regular-looking humans, like the ones that used to exist.

In the novel, do they ever directly address why unpowered children are murdered?